# How to create Custom regular expression with dynamic pattern which are used as data annotation for Model

Tags: c#

I want to apply custom regular expression as data annotation for all of my Model properties.

So I create a custom regular expression with dynamic pattern like below:-

`

```
 public class DynamicRegularExpressionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string PatternProperty { get;  set; }

        public Type Typeofclass { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
    

            PropertyInfo propertyinfo = Typeofclass.GetProperty(PatternProperty);

            //PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(PatternProperty);
            if (propertyinfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} is unknown property", propertyinfo));
            }
            var pattern = propertyinfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} must be a valid string regex",       pattern));
            }

            var str = value as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                // We consider that an empty string is valid for this property
                // Decorate with [Required] if this is not the case
                return null;
            }

            var match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
            if (!match.Success)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now my Data model similar to like this:-

```
 public class WeatherForecast
    {
        [DynamicRegularExpression(PatternProperty = "TemperatureC1", Typeofclass = typeof(WeatherForecastRegularExpression))]
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        [IsEmpty(ErrorMessage = "Should not be null or empty.")]
        [DynamicRegularExpression(PatternProperty = "Summary1",Typeofclass = typeof(WeatherForecastRegularExpression))]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

    }
```

So you can clearly observe that I need pass patternProperty as TemperatureC1 or Summary1 which are belongs to another class WeatherForecastRegularExpression.

Code for WeatherForecastRegularExpression.cs like this:-

```
  public static class WeatherForecastRegularExpression
    {
        public static string Summary1 => "a";

        public static string TemperatureC1 => "^-?[0-9][0-9,\\.]+$";   


    }
```

Actually  patterns for regularexpression is different for each properties(Summary,TemperatureC) and source of this pattern is sql data table.

Now what I want  to avoid these step to create WeatherForecastRegularExpression.cs class and define dummy properties like TemperatureC1 and Summary1 beacuse I have 6o to 7o nos of models in my projects. So it will be very difficult jobs for me.Also I don't want to change model class now by adding extra property into it. Only thing I want to add data annotation for my models.

So how I can make my DynamicRegularExpressionAttribute class more generic so that I can avoid these scenario.

Any suggestion or modification would  be helpful